# I have a problem with "csharp(CS0165)" and I don't know what i have done wrong

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm new to coding and tried to do a while loop, where you roll two dices until they show the same number. But when I put in my variables error "Use of unassigned local variable csharp(CS0165)". I don't know what to do to fix it.

I am coding in VS code with C# and.net framework.

My code

```
Random numberGen = new Random();
 int roll02;
 int roll01;
 int attemps;

 Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the dice");

 // The problem is with roll01 and roll02 in the while prentices.
 while(roll01!= roll02) {

     Console.ReadKey();

     roll01 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
     roll02 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);

     Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll01);
     Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll02);

 // the second problem is with the attemps under this line.
     attemps++;
 }

 Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attemps + "attemps to roll the same with the both dices");



 Console.ReadKey();
```

I haven't tried that much because I don't really understand the problem and when I try to change something it just creates more problems.

I would apricate some help please.

Comment: Neither of your `int` variables are assigned any values. What do you expect the comparison of two unassigned variables in the while loop evaluates to? You're probably looking for a do/while loop instead of a while loop. At the very least, you need to initialize `attemps` with some value (i.e. set it `= 0`)

Comment: It's important to carefully read the error message. I mean read it and understand each word. You can also lookup the error message. Most of the time, you will understand on your own.

Answer (score 3):

In c# values should be initialized/assigned values before being used. Most common `default` values for types would be:

```
int a = default    => int a = 0
string b = default => string b = null 
bool c = default   => bool c = false
int? a2 = default  => int? a2 = null
```

I would write it as this:

```
Random numberGen = new Random();
int roll02 = 0;
int roll01 = 0; 
int attemps = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Press enter to roll the dice");

do{
     Console.ReadKey();

     roll01 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
     roll02 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
     attempts++;

     Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll01);
     Console.WriteLine("You rolled: " + roll02);

 } while(roll01 != roll02)
 
 Console.WriteLine("It took you " + attemps + "attemps to roll the same with the both dices");
 Console.ReadKey();
```